# Visual C++ - the client of a library is unaware that the library has changed using pragma comment lib

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2005

The codebase I am working with uses pragma comment lib to express the dependencies of code to the library that it needs.  Its build is very broken.  I made an experiment to try to understand the use of pragma comment lib.  It is the simplest library and client of the library that I could produce.

```
Foo.lib
foo.cpp 
void foo() { printf("hello\n"); }
foo.h : 

#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib")
void foo();

FooTest.exe
main.cpp : 

#include "foo.h"
void main()
{
    foo();
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005 (for compatibility with a big commercial program that only accepts plugins made with this version).  The problem is that FooTest.exe does not recompile when foo.lib is updated.  I make a change to foo.cpp, save, build.  Then build the fooTest.exe solution.  The fooTest.exe solution does not seem to understand that its dependency has been changed.

I can get around this problem by adding the linker dependency to FooTest.exe but that defeats the entire point of pragma comment lib.

I have read many posts about pragma comment lib and figure it is working for lots of people.  In my overall codebase and my test it is not working.  I must be missing something.

Scott

Comment: It must be quite broken, a .lib file cannot affect compilation since it is only used by the linker.

Answer (score 1):

The `comment lib` pragma inserts a linker directive. The linker sees this and adds that library to its list of inputs. That is all it does. What you want is a project dependency, which you seem to know how to configure.

[Visual Studio 2005 pragma comment documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffcal/archive/2004/05/28/144286.aspx) of MSBuild (the build engine behind VS2010+ versions) and most probably of VCBuild (the engine in VS2005 builds), and really to every reasonable build engine:

[Dependency analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx) receives as input only the *project files* - either vcproj, vcxproj, make files or whatever.   If you inject the dependency into the *source files* (with #pragma lib), you are making it invisible to the build system altogether, thereby bypassing its dependency analysis and preventing a needed build when the dependency changes.

It is good practice to use pragma-comment-lib to express dependencies only on very stable components.  If you occasionally do need to respond to changes in the component, pragma lib is just not the tool for you.